# Pagination with SQL Server does not return the correct results

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pagination</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

// define how many results you want per page
$results_per_page = 3;
// find out the number of results stored in database
$AllRows = count($sql->query("SELECT * FROM $dbs[WEB2].._WebsiteNews")->fetchAll());
// determine number of total pages available
$number_of_pages = ceil($AllRows/$results_per_page);
// determine which page number visitor is currently on
if (!isset($_GET['news'])) {
  $page = 1;
} else {
  $page = $_GET['news'];
}
// determine the sql LIMIT starting number for the results on the displaying page
$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;
// retrieve selected results from database and display them on page
$PlayersQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $dbs[WEB2].._WebsiteNews ORDER BY No OFFSET $this_page_first_result ROWS FETCH NEXT $results_per_page ROWS ONLY ;";
    $query = $sql->Query1($PlayersQuery);
while ($row = $sql->QueryFetchArray($query)) {
  echo $row['No'] . ' ' . $row['Title']. '<br>';
}
// display the links to the pages
for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {
  echo '<a href="/news=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have like 7 pages, I only get same result (3 same result every page); no idea what is wrong with it.

I have been searching to make it with SQL Server but all have with MySQL; if someone knows how to make it work, please help me - thanks

Comment: I gave an answer based on MySQL. Are you trying to get it to work with MSSQL or MySQL?

Comment: MSSQL NOT MYSQL , i only found it working on mysql and trying to get it work on MSSQL as well .

Comment: What happens when you run the actual query generated in SQL Server? How many results do you get?

Comment: Showing example datasets with example results will probably get you more traction.

Comment: well here the result i get with my code http://prntscr.com/mouyx1 this first page http://prntscr.com/mouzc9 2nd page is the same result from first page also all pages is like that no idea why ... every page is show the same result from first page trying to fix it since 4 hours ^^

Answer (score 0):

MySQL

```
$PlayersQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $dbs[WEB2].._WebsiteNews ORDER BY No LIMIT $this_page_first_result, $results_per_page;";
```

MSSQL

```
$PlayersQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $dbs[WEB2].._WebsiteNews ORDER BY No 
OFFSET $this_page_first_result ROWS
FETCH NEXT $results_per_page ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: well this one for mysql not mssql

Answer (score 0):

well here the result i get with my code
http://prntscr.com/mouyx1 this first page
http://prntscr.com/mouzc9 2nd page is the same result from first page
also all pages is like that
no idea why ...
every page is show the same result from first page
trying to fix it since 4 hours ^^